# Validate float number using RegEx in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, regex, validation

I am trying to make a Numeric only `TextBox` in WPF and I have this code for it:

```
void NumericTextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = !IsValidInput(e.Text);
}

private bool IsValidInput(string p)
{
    switch (this.Type)
    {
        case NumericTextBoxType.Float:
            return Regex.Match(p, "^[0-9]*[.][0-9]*$").Success;
        case NumericTextBoxType.Integer:                    
        default:
            return Regex.Match(p, "^[0-9]*$").Success;                    
    }
}

// And also this!
public enum NumericTextBoxType
{
    Integer = 0, 
    Float = 1
}
```

When I set the type to Integer, it works well, but for Float, it does not.

I can use so many `NumericTextBox` controls out there, but I was wondering why this one is not working?

Comment: In what way, specifically, does it not work?

Comment: For `Integer`, it accepts integer numbers, but for `Float` it only accepts a period `.`.

Comment: Looks like Double.TryParse would work much better... But significantly less fun compared to RegExp...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try this:

```
@"^[0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]*)?$"
```

You need to escape the period. And making the period and decimal part optional is probably a good idea.

If you need to handle negative values you can add `-?` before the first `[0-9]` in each pattern.

**Update**

Tested as follows:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^[0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]*)?$");
Console.WriteLine(new bool[] {regex.IsMatch("blah"),
                              regex.IsMatch("12"),
                              regex.IsMatch(".3"),
                              regex.IsMatch("12.3"),
                              regex.IsMatch("12.3.4")});
```

results in

```
False 
True 
True 
True 
False
```

Comment: Nice work, but why the non-capturing group (`?:`)? Also, you don't need to escape a period in regex so the slash is redundant: `^[0-9]*(.[0-9]*)?$`. One could also allow whitespace before and after the number: `^\s*[0-9]*(.[0-9]*)?\s*$` though the same could be achieved with a `Trim` call on the input string. Finally, it's very important to keep in mind that `TryParse` is the right answer - this is just for fun :)

Comment: Ohad Schneider: The non-capturing group was just being pedantic.  We don't need the value of the group, so there's no point capturing it.

Comment: Ohad Schneider: As for the period, you do need to escape it if you want to match just a period.  If you don't escape it, it will match any character, which is not what we want. Your suggested pattern would match 123X456, for example.

Comment: My bad, I completely forgot period was the wildcard for any character (except \n). My regex-foo is rusty indeed...

Comment: it will work with 0, whereas it is invalid value for double. It should be 0.0

Answer (score 13):

I urge you to use [`Double.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx) method instead of regex validation. Using `TryParse()` let your application to be a bit more universal in terms of culture. When current culture changes, `TryParse()` will parse with no problem. Also `TryParse()` methods believed to have no bugs as they were tested by .net community.

But in case of regex your should change your validation expression hence it could be no relevant to new culture.

You can rewrite code like this:

```
private bool IsValidInput(string p)
{
    switch (this.Type)
    {
        case NumericTextBoxType.Float:
            double doubleResult;
            return double.TryParse(p, out doubleResult);
        case NumericTextBoxType.Integer:                    
        default:
            int intResult;
            return int.TryParse(p, out intResult);
    }
}
```

You can even add your own extension methods to make parsing part more elegant.

```
public static double? TryParseInt(this string source)
{
    double result;
    return double.TryParse(source, out result) ? result : (double?)null;
}

// usage
bool ok = source.TryParseInt().HasValue;
```

Comment: Your option but a little bit shorter: private bool IsValid(string p) => this.IsFloatingPoint ? double.TryParse(p, out var d) : int.TryParse(p, out var i);

Answer (score 4):

Check out the `TryParse` static methods you will find on double, float, and int.

They return true if the string can be parsed (by the `Parse` method).

Answer (score 2):

`[-+]?\d+(.\d+)?`

The most simple regex for float. It it doesn't match the cases '123.' or '.123'.

Also, you should look on context culture:

```
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
var decimalSeparator = ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
var floatRegex = string.Format(@"[-+]?\d+({0}\d+)?", decimalSeparator);
```

Comment: You need to escape the `.` like this: `\.`

Answer (score 2):

I tried the solution approved above, found that it will fail if user enters a dot only
`@"^[0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]*)?$"`.

So, I modified it to:

```
@"^[0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]+)?$"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a code I came up by mixing replies from @Andrew Cooper and @Ramesh. Added the dictionary code so any body thinking of testing the code can run as many test cases the easy way.

```
//greater than or equal to zero floating point numbers
Regex floating = new Regex(@"^[0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]+)?$");
        Dictionary<string, bool> test_cases = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
        test_cases.Add("a", floating.IsMatch("a"));
        test_cases.Add("a.3", floating.IsMatch("a.3"));
        test_cases.Add("0", floating.IsMatch("0"));
        test_cases.Add("-0", floating.IsMatch("-0"));
        test_cases.Add("-1", floating.IsMatch("-1"));
        test_cases.Add("0.1", floating.IsMatch("0.1"));
        test_cases.Add("0.ab", floating.IsMatch("0.ab"));

        test_cases.Add("12", floating.IsMatch("12"));
        test_cases.Add(".3", floating.IsMatch(".3"));
        test_cases.Add("12.3", floating.IsMatch("12.3"));
        test_cases.Add("12.3.4", floating.IsMatch("12.3.4"));
        test_cases.Add(".", floating.IsMatch("."));

        test_cases.Add("0.3", floating.IsMatch("0.3"));
        test_cases.Add("12.31252563", floating.IsMatch("12.31252563"));
        test_cases.Add("-12.31252563", floating.IsMatch("-12.31252563"));

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, bool> pair in test_cases)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pair.Key.ToString() + "  -  " + pair.Value);
        }
```