# C#: Change NumberDecimalSeparator for Regex

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, numbers

I'm parsing decimal values with a decimal separator using regex, that are in US format, like: 2.56

But my system's culture decimal separator is set to a comma, so when I use the decimal class \d, the regex fails to recognize "2.56" as a valid decimal number.

I would like to stick to the \d for the sake of readability and simplicity. Can I force it to recognize dot as a decimal separator?

When using float.TryParse(), I can enforce it to use dot as a decimal separator:

```
var usCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
float.TryParse(text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Number, usCulture, out s )
```

Can I do something similar for regex?

I tried changing current thread's culture:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

but it doesn't seem to affect the regex, it still expects comma as a decimal separator.

Comment: `\d`  matches a digit, not a "number", and does not match any decimal separators.

Comment: I misread the documentation then. There is no built-in class that matches a decimal number, it must be matched manually?

Comment: @Yekoor, yes you have to put the pattern manually, something like `^-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107673/validate-float-number-using-regex-in-c-sharp

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273141/regex-for-numbers-only

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968825/regular-expression-for-decimal-number

Comment: And after the match - what are you doing with those numbers?

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to stick to the `\d` for the sake of readability and simplicity. Can I force it to recognize dot as a decimal separator?

No, that is because `\d` is shorthand for `[0-9]`. It doesn't match for anything else, including separators.

If you want to match decimals, you need something like this:

```
-?\d+(\.\d+)?
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/z7d8Tv/1)

Answer (score 1):

Well, `\d` is a any unicode *digit*, not a *floating point number*. If you insist on *Regular Expressions* you have to construct pattern manually; in the simplest case (no *exponential part*, no *thousand separator*, *arbitrary length* etc.) it can be

```
  string escapedSeparator = Regex.Escape(
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);

  string pattern = $"^-?[0-9]+({escapedSeparator}[0-9]+)?$";

  if (Regex.IsMatch("-123.456", pattern)) {
    ...
  }
```

I *really doubt* if it's better than `double.TryParse(...)` which has been *specially designed* for this purpose.